# Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, protractor, cucumber

I am getting this error while Running a protractor code.

*Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"*

Below is the code-

```
''' const { Given, And, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
    const expect = require('chai').expect;
    var util = require('util');
    var fs = require('fs');

    // Search ELD Provider
    Then("I click on search Provider feild" , async ()=> {
      await $fk.textbox("Search Provider").enter_value("peoplenet");
      await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
      await $fk.base_page.loaderWait(false);
    });

    Then("I am able to see this provider record on screen" , async ()=> {
      let a = await element(by.css("div.app-content-wrapper.facility-manager-wrapper div.mainContent app-my-eld.ng-star-inserted:nth-child(2) div.main-content div.ng-star-inserted:nth-child(3) div.ui-table.ui-widget.ui-table-hoverable-rows div.ui-table-scrollable-wrapper.ng-star-inserted div.ui-table-scrollable-view div.ui-table-scrollable-body table.ui-table-scrollable-body-table tbody.ui-table-tbody tr.ui-selectable-row.ui-state-highlight.ng-star-inserted td.table-column.ng-star-inserted:nth-child(2) > span.ng-star-inserted"));
      console.log(a.getText());
    });

    Then("I clear the Search feild" , async ()=> {
      await $fk.textbox("Search Provider").clear();
    });

    // Click on Add ELD button
    When("I click on Add provider button" , async ()=> {
      await $fk.button(" Add ELD ").click();
    });

    /*Then("I Click on cancel and Reclick on Add Provider Button" , async ()=> {
      await $fk.textbox("Search Provider").clear();
    });*/

    When("I select a Truck ELD or Trailer GPS" , async ()=> {
      await $fk.radiobutton(" Truck ELD ").click();
    });

    Then("I select Location Provider & Authorize the details" , async ()=>{
    //user will enter identification number here
      await $fk.lookup("ng-input").click();
      await $fk.lookup("ng-input").enter_value("Afaqy")
      await $fk.base_page.loaderWait(false);
      await $fk.base_page.click_on_first_suggestion();
      await $fk.textbox("Enter username").enter_value("unilever-sanad");
      await $fk.textbox("Enter password").enter_value("qwerty");
    });

    Then("I click on Terms and conditions Checkbox and click on next" , async ()=>{
      await $fk.checkbox("mat-checkbox-inner-container").mouse_move();
      await $fk.checkbox("mat-checkbox-inner-container").click();
    });

    Then("I click on Next to go to next page",async () => {
      //await $fk.button("Next").click();
      await $fk.button("Next").click();
      await browser.sleep(10000);
    });

    Then("I Enter Asset id" , async ()=>{
      await $fk.textbox("Asset ID").enter_value("9998");
      await $fk.button("Locate").click();
      await $fk.base_page.loaderWait(false);
    });

    Then("I Click on Add location Provider" , async ()=>{
      await $fk.button("Add Location Provider").click();
    });

    Then ("I click on Logout" , async ()=>{
      await $fk.button("Done").click();
      await element(by.xpath("//img[@class='image']")).click();
      await browser.sleep(1000);
      //It will click on Log Out Button
      await $fk.dropdown("Log Out").click();
      await browser.sleep(1000);
      browser.quit();
    });'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protractor: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977422/protractor-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-both-angu)

Comment: Hey @SergeyPleshakov - this issue is resolved. Thanks i made these 2 changes in my code. `browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;`
`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`